# FastAPI/Redoc created 'openapi.json' is missing 'type' key for Enum params

Tags: python, rest, openapi, fastapi, redoc

I have a REST API build using FastAPI, with various query string params that are all working fine, generating working `openapi.json` output:

```py
flagged: bool = False,
```

Generates:

```
{
  "required": false,
  "schema": {
    "title": "Flagged",
    "type": "boolean"
  },
  "name": "flagged",
  "in": "query"
}
```

However I have some params that use Enum values. The resulting openAPI definition is missing a `type` specifier -

```py
sortby: TaskSortby = TaskSortby.confusion,
```

Generates:

```
 {
  "required": false,
  "schema": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TaskSortby"
      }
    ],
    "default": "confusion"
  },
  "name": "sortby",
  "in": "query"
}
```

As you can see `schema.type` is missing, which causes other tools that read `openapi.json` files to break.

**How can I generate an `openapi.json` with `type` key for Enum params?**

Comment: It cannot contain `type` because it uses [AllOf](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/#allof) keyword for referencing to subschemas, which already contains `type` attribute

Comment: @alex_noname surely the enum param should then use the `type` from the subschemas?

Comment: I think so. Perhaps the tools do not support OpenAPI 3.0